# PostgreSQL - Eliminate like rows, but only for certain values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table with three columns - id, name, and gender.  There might be multiple ids with the same name.  There may also be multiple genders for the same name.

For all but one name, I'm completely ok with there being both a row for female and a row for male, and even a row for intersex and so on.  However, for Daniel and only Daniel, I cannot allow there to be both a male row and a female row (though intersex, etc is completely ok).  If there is both a row for male and  row for female with Daniel's name, I'd like to eliminate the male row, leaving only the female row and any other genders that were present.

```
id | name   | gender
---+--------+---------
1  | Andrew | male
1  | Andrew | female
2  | Andrew | female
1  | Megan  | male
1  | Megan  | female
1  | Megan  | intersex
2  | Megan  | male
2  | Megan  | female
4  | Megan  | intersex
1  | Daniel | male      -- this row must be eliminated...
1  | Daniel | female    -- beacuse this row is present.
1  | Daniel | intersex  -- But this one is totally cool.
1  | Daniel | porcupine -- So is this one.
2  | Daniel | male      -- this row must be eliminated...
2  | Daniel | female    -- beacuse this row is present.
3  | Daniel | male      -- But this row is totally cool, 
                        -- because there's no female Daniel row
                        -- with an id of 3.
```

How can I go about removing those rows? I have a sneaking suspicion I'm missing something really obvious...

Comment: Let's say that your `id` field is not a primary key. Then: what is it? Does your table _have_ a primary key ?

Comment: Can there be multiple female 'Daniel' per `id`? And you'd want to keep all or just one? In this case, which one?

Comment: Good question, Erwin, didn't mean to leave it ambiguous. There can only be one name/gender pair for each id.

I just made the table above up to give a simpler version of my problem. The table I'm actually working with is far more intricate. I used id as a general field which could be anything. I didn't mean for its name to suggest that it's a primary key. My bad, wildplasser!

But Daniel's brave contribution was exactly the answer I needed, so this problem is resolved. Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DELETE FROM tablename t WHERE name='Daniel' AND gender='male'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename
              WHERE name='Daniel' AND id=t.id AND gender='female');
```

Comment: That's decidedly selfless help. :)